# dropdown menu opens into the table and is not visible

Tags: html, css

I have an operations field in a table. Clicking on this field opens the dropdown. The dropdown that opens remains in the table and automatic scrolling appears. How do I get the dropdown dropdown table out of the way.

[image]

HTML

```
 <td>
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle hide-arrow py-0" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
   <i data-feather="more-vertical"></i>
 </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
  <i data-feather="edit-2" class="me-50"></i>
  <span>Stok Hareketleri</span>
  </a>
  <a data-idd="@item.StokID" class="dropdown-item btnSil" href="#">
      <i data-feather="x" class="me-50"></i>
       <span>Sil</span>
   </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </td>
```

CSS

```
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0px auto auto 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    transform: translate(-124px, 26px);
    display:block;
```

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the z-index would get the job done for you

```css
.selector {
    z-index: 1000
}
```

Comment: unfortunately not working

Comment: Have you set the position value of the parent element as relative?

Comment: it doesn't work that way either

Comment: If you have set it to relative, change it to block